# Show textview from its start

Tags: android, textview

By an array, when I press a button show new text in a textview (scrollable).

So, if a read the text in a textview until half page and press the button, new textview show me new text NOT from start of it but with same position of last textview.

How I resolve this problem?

thanks!

Comment: This question is really confusing to read. If you post the code that you have it would allow us to help you easier

Comment: sorry for my english :-( there's a lot of code... ok, image a textview scrollable by user. I put a text in that textview, I scoll half text view and when I press a button, now, new text show in that textview, but new textview doesn't start from start of it.

Comment: No problem. So, you want a textview but if there's overflow, you can show the rest in a scrollview? I'm sure there is a lot of code but even a little that may be relevant helps people to get a feel for what you want and what you have done so far.

Comment: So do you want the text view to stay in the same position as you scroll the image??? and then do you want the text to change on a button push?

Answer (score 0):

Going to take a wild stab in the dark that when you mention scrolling text view, you are referring to a EditText view. If this is the case, you can set the position of the cursor in an EditText by using the [setSelection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setSelection%28int%29) function. To return to the start, you would use setSelection(0).